# Clearing memory of a subkernel in a Do loop

Tags: memory

I have a `Do` loop, which saves data directly to a `.txt` file.  However when I leave it running for long periods of time the RAM starts to run out till finally my laptop crashes.  I've read similar posts on here but nothing seems to have worked.

After each run of the `Do` loop, I no longer need the data because it has been saved in a `.txt` file.  This means I don't require *Mathematica* to use up my RAM remembering it... but I can't get it to stop!

I tried putting  `ClearSystemCache[]` inside the `Do` loop at the end but this didnt work.  I read somewhere that this could be because I need to clear the memory of the individual subkernels.

What is meant by subkernel?  I run `ParallelEvaluate[]` and it launches four kernels, one for each CPU.   Are these 4 kernels called subkernels?  If so what is 'sub' about them?
But the main question is how do i go about clearing the memory of the subkernals?

My set up is

```
ParallelEvaluate[
        Do[ 
           (bulk of formulae)
           If[ (condition), PutAppend[ ]     ]
          ]
                ]
```

I have tried putting

```
ParallelEvaluate[
        Do[ 
          (bulk of formulae)
          If[ (condition), PutAppend[ ]     ]
          ClearSystemCache[]
          ]
                ]
```

However this doesnt seem to work.

I've also tried:

- putting `$HistoryLength = 0;` at the start of the `Do` loop  (doesn't change anything)
- putting `` Clear["Global`*"] ``
- putting `` Remove["Global`*"] ``  inside end of `Do` loop (gives an error)

If someone could explain how to clear memory of subkernels and/or give any other suggestions that would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Try `Unprotect[Out]; Clear[Out];`.

Comment: @kingmonkeywoman Are you using `Module` for defining your functions? In afirmative case, this might be the issue. @chyaong in such case, your suggestion won't work, because of the bug described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867892/reducing-memory-usage-in-an-extended-mathematica-session/6873142#6873142

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to clear the memory of the subkernels is like this, for a variable

pc =.;
delete it in the master kernel

DistributeDefinitions[pc]

distribute the definition

Touch the two commands I hope it helps you.

Comment: The easiest way is run `CloseKernels[]` after each one-two loops with following `LaunchKernels[]`. Any attempts of calling of `ClearAll[]` or something else for local clearing of variables finally lead to growing amount of garbage in memory. But starting from the MMA13, the memory management became much better than before.. Previously it was shit.