# Is this buggy behavoir of Module solved?

Tags: scoping, memory

I have just found out about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6867892/2853667) bug of `Module`, i.e. the creation of ["zombie"-variables](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/c/tZm0W5wxLpc) in some cases (see also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31923/8822) post).

I couldn't find a post saying that it has been solved: did I miss it somehow?

**EDIT** According to the links provided above, it seems that some definitions might leak out of `Module`. In the second link, the following code is given:

```
a[b_] := Module[{c, d},
c[___] := (Print[c];);
d[___] := (Print[d];);
c[];
d[] /; b === 1
]
```

By running it, we have:

```
In[6]:= a[1];
During evaluation of In[6]:= c$6798
During evaluation of In[6]:= d$6798
```

However, looking into the variable defined in the context, we have:

```
In[7]:= Names[$Context <> "*"]
Out[7]= {"a", "b", "c", "c$", "d", "d$", "d$6798"}
```

The last variable should not be there. Is this a bug? Has this been solved, somehow?

Comment: I voted to close because this question isn't self-contained.  Please add some code here to demonstrate the issue at hand, don't make people click out to one of three other posts and try to guess what your question is.

Comment: @JasonB. Better  now?

Comment: It is better. The `Module` you have there looks like it is specifically made to leak the `d` variable, so I would put it in the not-a-bug category.

Comment: Definitely by design, so NAB.

Answer (score 14):

IMHO, this is not a bug, but a feature. It allows you to implement pointer-like data structures with garbage collection because symbols in a `Module` have the `Temporary` attribute. They are automatically deleted when they are no longer referenced. But beware that `Out` can still store references if `$HistoryLength` is not set to `0`.

Here an example:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

ClearAll[pointer];
SetAttributes[pointer, HoldAll]

(*Constructor*)
pointer /: Init[pointer, data_] := Module[{container},
   container = data;
   pointer[container]
   ];

(*Mutable modification*)
pointer /: Modify[x : pointer[container_], key_String, value_] := (container[[key]] = value;);

(*Deep copy*)
pointer /: DeepCopy[x : pointer[container_]] := Init[pointer, container];
```

So much for the implementation of the data structure. Here a demonstration of its capabilities:

```
(*Initialization*)
P = Init[pointer, Association["a" -> 1, "b" -> 2]];
(*Shallow copy*)
Q = P;
(*Ieep copy*)
R = DeepCopy[P];
"This is P" -> P
"This is Q" -> Q
"This is R" -> R
"Memory usage on containers" -> (# -> ByteCount[ToExpression[#]] & /@ Names["*`container$*"])


"Contents of Q" -> Q[[1]]

(*Modification affects  the pointee, not the pointer.*)
Modify[P, "a", 3];
"This is P after modification of P" -> P[[1]]
"This is Q after modification of P" -> Q[[1]]
(*It does not affect the deep copy.*)
"This is Q after modification of P" -> R[[1]]


(*... and we have garbage collection!*)
P =.;
Q =.;
"Memory usage on containers after references P and Q are deleted" -> (# -> ByteCount[ToExpression[#]] & /@ Names["*`container$*"])
```

This is what it returns:

> ```
> "This is P" -> pointer[container$1632]
> ```

> ```
> "This is Q" -> pointer[container$1632]
> ```

> ```
> "This is R" -> pointer[container$1633]
> ```

> ```
> "Memory usage on containers" -> 
> {"container$" -> 0, "container$1632" -> 392, "container$1633" -> 392}
> ```

> ```
> "Contents of Q" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>
> ```

> ```
> "This is P after modification of P" -> <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 2|>
> ```

> ```
> "This is Q after modification of P" -> <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 2|>
> ```

> ```
> "This is R after modification of P" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>
> ```

> ```
> "Memory usage on containers after references P and Q are deleted" -> 
> {"container$" -> 0, "container$1633" -> 424}
> ```

Please don't ask me why the size of `container$1633` has grown by 32 Byte. I don't know. I guess it is somehow due to lazy copying of the `Association`.